# Problem with powershell script for AD server Status

Tags: powershell, active-directory, inventory

I have a script that can have a list of AD servers (with Get-ADComputer) and the results goes to a TXT file. I don't know how to only have Online Servers only. I only need their names.

I tried to do some IF {} Else{} with the cmdlet Test-Connection -CN $Server but it doesn't work (I'm probably doing it wrong). Here is my code :

```
$TXTFile = "C:\Scripts\Serv.txt"

$TXTOutput = @()

Write-Host "INFO: Finding servers from AD"

$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*server*" -and Enabled -eq $true} | SORT Name
Write-Host "INFO:"$Servers.Count"Records found"

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

    $ServerHash = $NULL
    $ServerHash = [ordered]@{
        "Servers Name" = $Server.Name
    }
    $TXTOutput += New-Object PSObject -Property $ServerHash
}
$TXTOutput
```

I want, if possible, to have all of my AD Online Servers name in a TXT file. For now I only have all of my servers (Online and Offline). It's my first post so sorry if I made it wrong !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Quiet` parameter with `Test-Connection` cmdlet in order to get just `True` or `False` and then make a decision based on that result.

```
$TXTFile = "C:\Temp\Serv.txt"
$TXTOutput = @()
$servers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*server*" -and Enabled -eq $true} | select -expandproperty Name
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    if ((Test-Connection $Server -Count 2 -Quiet) -eq $true) {
        $TXTOutput += $Server
    }
}
$TXTOutput | Out-File $TXTFile
```

You can pipe `$TXTOutput` to `sort` if you want. Keep in mind that this might take a while since you are basically pinging each server twice `-Count 2`.